# How to watch route in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I can't figure out how to watch routes in Nuxt3.

In Nuxt2 was very easy to make it in any component. Did anyone knows how can i write this in Nuxt3?

```html
<script>
export default {
  ....
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      console.log('route change to', to)
      console.log('route change from', from)
    },
  },
  ....
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
  const menu = reactive({isOpen: false});

  const route = useRoute();

  watch(route, value => {
    menu.isOpen = false
  }, {deep: true, immediate: true})
</script>
```

Comment: u have really saved my day

Comment: This used to work fine but not anymore, maybe something changed in the last Nuxt version or so. Anyway, the hadicodes' answer is working fine, and it maybe makes more sense since it watches only for the path to change, not the route as the whole object.

Comment: Not working. hadicodes Answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 14):

The "myvariable" either can be boolean or string or whatever.

```
<script setup>

const myvariable = ref(true)

watch(
  () => route.path,
  () => {
    do my function or
    myvariable.value = false
  },
);
```

The "myvariable" either can be boolean or string or whatever.

Answer (score 9):

Supporting Hadicodes answer, Nuxt v^3.7.4

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const route = useRoute();
const isMobileNavOpen = ref(false);

watch(() => route.fullPath, () => {
    isMobileNavOpen.value = false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
watch(
  () => route.fullPath,
  () => {
    set(menuOpened, false);
  },
);
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

For Nuxt.js v3.8.0, if you are using Typescript it is not possible to directly watch `route`, it is required to watch `route` properties. So you need to use this structure of watch (as mentioned on [Vue.js docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers)):

```
watch(
  () => route.path,
  (newRoute) => {
    // your code here on route change...
  }
)
```

But mention that `watch` trigger works only after page load (SSR rendering and maybe your API requests). So, for the mobile menu, as in examples above, I would recommend to directly watch clicks on `<nuxt-link>` for faster UI reactions.

Answer (score 0):

Neither proposed options were working for me, but i found another way:

```
    const objToWatch = (any object that changes on route change, like asyncData);

    watchEffect(async () => {
        objToWatch
        console.log("route changed")
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
const { name: routeName } = useRoute();
const isHome = computed(() => routeName === Route.HOME);
```